# Creating a search function for appointments with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, sorting, search

I'm in a group assignment where the current task is making a search function where the user can search the records with keywords. The keywords are case insensitive. Examples are: If a user searches a, anything that has a in subject for the venue will be displayed, it could be class or Toowoomba, everything that contains a. The same goes for numbers; if 1 is searched, it doesn't matter where it includes it, but it must be displayed.

I think everything is being sorted correctly, but I'm having trouble making it display. If anyone could help, I would thoroughly appreciate it.

```js
    
                var list = [{date: "12/12/2020",
                             startTime: "08:00",
                             endTime: "09:00",
                             subject: "Mathematics",
                             venue: "Lab 10",
                             priority: "High"},]           
                function searchFucntion(searchValue, searchArray) {
                
                function displayResults()
                {
                return "<tr><td>" + this.date + "</td><td>" + this.startTime + "</td><td>" + this.endTime + "</td><td>" + this.subject + "</td><td>" + this.venue + "</td><td>" + this.priority + "</td></tr>";
                }
    
                let searchObject = {
                    date: "",
                    startTime: "",
                    endTime: "",
                    subject: "",
                    venue: "",
                    priority: "",
                    rowData: function () {
                        "<tr><td>" + this.date + "</td><td>" + this.startTime + "</td><td>" + this.endTime + "</td><td>" + this.subject + "</td><td>" + this.venue + "</td><td>" + this.priority + "</td></tr>";
                    }}
                    let objectEntryTest = Object.create(searchObject)
    
                searchArray = list
                searchValue = document.getElementById("searchInput").value;
                searchValue = searchValue.toLowerCase();
                var tempList = [];
                var i;
                var j;
                var temp;
                for (i = 0; i < searchArray.length; i++) {
    
                    if (list[i].date.indexOf(searchValue) != -1 ||
                    list[i].startTime.indexOf(searchValue) != -1 ||
                    list[i].endTime.indexOf(searchValue) != -1 ||
                    list[i].subject.indexOf(searchValue) != -1 ||
                    list[i].venue.indexOf(searchValue) != -1 ||
                    list[i].priority.indexOf(searchValue) != -1) {
                        searchObject.date = searchArray[i].date
                        searchObject.startTime = searchArray[i].startTime
                        searchObject.endTime = searchArray[i].endTime
                        searchObject.subject = searchArray[i].subject
                        searchObject.venue = searchArray[i].venue
                        searchObject.priority = searchArray[i].priority
                        tempList.push(searchObject)
                    }
                }
                for (i = 0; i < tempList.length - 1; i++) {
                    for (j = 0; j < tempList.length - 1; j++) {
                        if (tempList[j].date.substring(0, 2) < tempList[j + 1].date.substring(0, 2)) {
                            temp = tempList[j];
                            tempList[j] = tempList[j + 1];
                            tempList[j + 1] = temp;
                        }
                    }
                }
                for (i = 0; i < tempList.length - 1; i++) {
                    for (j = 0; j < tempList.length - 1; j++) {
                        if (tempList[j].date.substring(3, 5) < tempList[j + 1].date.substring(3, 5)) {
                            temp = tempList[j];
                            tempList[j] = tempList[j + 1];
                            tempList[j + 1] = temp;
                        }
                    }
                }
                for (i = 0; i < tempList.length - 1; i++) {
                    for (j = 0; j < tempList.length - 1; j++) {
                        if (tempList[j].date.substring(6, 10) < tempList[j + 1].date.substring(6, 10)) {
                            temp = tempList[j];
                            tempList[j] = tempList[j + 1];
                            tempList[j + 1] = temp;
                        }
                    }
                }
                for (i = 0; i = tempList.length; i++) {
                    let sResultTable = document.getElementById("sResultTable");
                    sResultTable.innerHTML += displayResults(tempList[i]);
                }
            }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <body>
        <script>

    
    
        </script>
        <title>Diary</title>
        <h1 style="text-align: center;">Diary</h1>
        <form>
            <table bgcolor="#cccccc" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td align="right">Date</td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="date" name="date" size="10" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy"></td>
                    <td align="right">Start Time</td>
                    <td>
                        <select id="startTime">
                            <option value="08:00">08:00</option>
                            <option value="09:00">09:00</option>
                            <option value="10:00">10:00</option>
                            <option value="11:00">11:00</option>
                            <option value="12:00">12:00</option>
                            <option value="13:00">13:00</option>
                            <option value="14:00">14:00</option>
                            <option value="15:00">15:00</option>
                            <option value="16:00">16:00</option>
                            <option value="17:00">17:00</option>
                            <option value="18:00">18:00</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td align="right">End Time</td>
                    <td>
                        <select id="endTime">
                            <option value="08:00">08:00</option>
                            <option value="09:00">09:00</option>
                            <option value="10:00">10:00</option>
                            <option value="11:00">11:00</option>
                            <option value="12:00">12:00</option>
                            <option value="13:00">13:00</option>
                            <option value="14:00">14:00</option>
                            <option value="15:00">15:00</option>
                            <option value="16:00">16:00</option>
                            <option value="17:00">17:00</option>
                            <option value="18:00">18:00</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
    
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right">Subject:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="subject" size="10"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right">Venue:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="venue" size="10"></td>
                </tr>
    
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top" align="center">Priority</td>
                    <td><input type="radio" id="high" name="Priority" value="High" checked="true" /> High<br />
                    <td><input type="radio" id="medium" name="Priority" value="Medium" /> Medium<br />
                    <td><input type="radio" id="low" name="Priority" value="Low" /> Low<br />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td><input type="button" value="Add Appointment" onclick="addAppointment()" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td><input type="button" value="Search" onclick="searchFucntion()" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">Search:</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="searchInput" size="10"></td>
            </tr>
            <hr>
    
            <div>
                <table align="center" width="80%" height="150px" cellpadding="1px" cellspacing="1px" border="1" id="table1">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th width="50">Date</th>
                            <th width="20">Start</th>
                            <th width="20">End</th>
                            <th width="75">Subject</th>
                            <th width="60">Venue</th>
                            <th width="5">Priority</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="tbody"> </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td><input type="reset" value="Randomise Appointments" onclick="shuffleAppointments()" /></td>
                <td></td><input type="button" value="Sort Appointments" onclick="sortRecords()" /></td>
                <td>by</td>
                <td>
                    <select id="Date">
                        <option value="date">Date</option>
                        <option value="startTime">Start Time</option>
                        <option value="endTime">End Time</option>
                        <option value="subject">Subject</option>
                        <option value="venue">Venue</option>
                        <option value="priority">Priority</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <hr>Search Results
            <div>
                <table align="center" width="80%" height="150px" cellpadding="1px" cellspacing="1px" border="1" id="table1">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th width="50">Date</th>
                            <th width="20">Start</th>
                            <th width="20">End</th>
                            <th width="75">Subject</th>
                            <th width="60">Venue</th>
                            <th width="5">Priority</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="sResultTable"> </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            </hr>
    
    
    
    
            </table>
        </form>
    
    
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please may you fix the syntax errors in your example?

Comment: Define “trouble making it display”. Unrelated, but it seems like there’s an awful lot of code here for this functionality.

Comment: @Dave Newton Its part of a much larger project sorry this is only a small part, hence all the other code hah. Im having trouble trying to make the search results display

Comment: @evolutionxbox Im sorry, Done now

Comment: I’m saying there’s a lot of unnecessary code here that can be eliminated without changing the functionality. Repeating that you’re having trouble displaying search results doesn’t help; the point is to describe what should happen, what is happening, etc as described in the how-to-ask page.

Comment: Sorry about that, I am posting on behalf of another person in my group and it can be hard to communicate the issue. It sounds like he may have solved the problem but thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was essentially 3 things wrong with your code

1. `displayResult` dis not take any parameter yet you were passing the result to display to it - add an argument (`res` below) and change `this` to `res`
2. The loop where you were trying to display the result was not set up correctly. The loop was doing `for (i = 0; i = tempList.length; i++)` change to `for (i = 0; i < tempList.length; i++)`.
3. You were not clearing the table between searches so I added `sResultTable.innerHTML = "";` before displaying results.

There are a lot of other improvements which could be made to your code which I've skipped for now - that will get you going.

In addition, I don't know what the repeated loops were for so I removed them for the sake of brevity to show a working example below:

```js
var list = [{date: "12/12/2020",
             startTime: "08:00",
             endTime: "09:00",
             subject: "Mathematics",
             venue: "Lab 10",
             priority: "High"},]           
function searchFucntion(searchValue, searchArray) {

function displayResults(res)
{
  return "<tr><td>" + res.date + "</td><td>" + res.startTime + "</td><td>" + res.endTime + "</td><td>" + res.subject + "</td><td>" + res.venue + "</td><td>" + res.priority + "</td></tr>";
}

let searchObject = {
    date: "",
    startTime: "",
    endTime: "",
    subject: "",
    venue: "",
    priority: "",
    rowData: function () {
        "<tr><td>" + this.date + "</td><td>" + this.startTime + "</td><td>" + this.endTime + "</td><td>" + this.subject + "</td><td>" + this.venue + "</td><td>" + this.priority + "</td></tr>";
    }}
    let objectEntryTest = Object.create(searchObject)

searchArray = list
searchValue = document.getElementById("searchInput").value;
searchValue = searchValue.toLowerCase();
var tempList = [];
var i;
var j;
var temp;
for (i = 0; i < searchArray.length; i++) {

    if (list[i].date.indexOf(searchValue) != -1 ||
    list[i].startTime.indexOf(searchValue) != -1 ||
    list[i].endTime.indexOf(searchValue) != -1 ||
    list[i].subject.indexOf(searchValue) != -1 ||
    list[i].venue.indexOf(searchValue) != -1 ||
    list[i].priority.indexOf(searchValue) != -1) {
        searchObject.date = searchArray[i].date
        searchObject.startTime = searchArray[i].startTime
        searchObject.endTime = searchArray[i].endTime
        searchObject.subject = searchArray[i].subject
        searchObject.venue = searchArray[i].venue
        searchObject.priority = searchArray[i].priority
        tempList.push(searchObject)
    }
}
sResultTable.innerHTML = "";
for (i = 0; i < tempList.length; i++) {
    let sResultTable = document.getElementById("sResultTable");
    sResultTable.innerHTML += displayResults(tempList[i]);
}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <body>
        <script>

    
    
        </script>
        <title>Diary</title>
        <h1 style="text-align: center;">Diary</h1>
        <form>
            <table bgcolor="#cccccc" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td align="right">Date</td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="date" name="date" size="10" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy"></td>
                    <td align="right">Start Time</td>
                    <td>
                        <select id="startTime">
                            <option value="08:00">08:00</option>
                            <option value="09:00">09:00</option>
                            <option value="10:00">10:00</option>
                            <option value="11:00">11:00</option>
                            <option value="12:00">12:00</option>
                            <option value="13:00">13:00</option>
                            <option value="14:00">14:00</option>
                            <option value="15:00">15:00</option>
                            <option value="16:00">16:00</option>
                            <option value="17:00">17:00</option>
                            <option value="18:00">18:00</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td align="right">End Time</td>
                    <td>
                        <select id="endTime">
                            <option value="08:00">08:00</option>
                            <option value="09:00">09:00</option>
                            <option value="10:00">10:00</option>
                            <option value="11:00">11:00</option>
                            <option value="12:00">12:00</option>
                            <option value="13:00">13:00</option>
                            <option value="14:00">14:00</option>
                            <option value="15:00">15:00</option>
                            <option value="16:00">16:00</option>
                            <option value="17:00">17:00</option>
                            <option value="18:00">18:00</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
    
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right">Subject:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="subject" size="10"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right">Venue:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="venue" size="10"></td>
                </tr>
    
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top" align="center">Priority</td>
                    <td><input type="radio" id="high" name="Priority" value="High" checked="true" /> High<br />
                    <td><input type="radio" id="medium" name="Priority" value="Medium" /> Medium<br />
                    <td><input type="radio" id="low" name="Priority" value="Low" /> Low<br />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td><input type="button" value="Add Appointment" onclick="addAppointment()" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td><input type="button" value="Search" onclick="searchFucntion()" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">Search:</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="searchInput" size="10"></td>
            </tr>
            <hr>
    
            <div>
                <table align="center" width="80%" height="150px" cellpadding="1px" cellspacing="1px" border="1" id="table1">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th width="50">Date</th>
                            <th width="20">Start</th>
                            <th width="20">End</th>
                            <th width="75">Subject</th>
                            <th width="60">Venue</th>
                            <th width="5">Priority</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="tbody"> </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td><input type="reset" value="Randomise Appointments" onclick="shuffleAppointments()" /></td>
                <td></td><input type="button" value="Sort Appointments" onclick="sortRecords()" /></td>
                <td>by</td>
                <td>
                    <select id="Date">
                        <option value="date">Date</option>
                        <option value="startTime">Start Time</option>
                        <option value="endTime">End Time</option>
                        <option value="subject">Subject</option>
                        <option value="venue">Venue</option>
                        <option value="priority">Priority</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <hr>Search Results
            <div>
                <table align="center" width="80%" height="150px" cellpadding="1px" cellspacing="1px" border="1" id="table1">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th width="50">Date</th>
                            <th width="20">Start</th>
                            <th width="20">End</th>
                            <th width="75">Subject</th>
                            <th width="60">Venue</th>
                            <th width="5">Priority</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="sResultTable"> </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            </hr>
    
    
    
    
            </table>
        </form>
    
    
    </body>
</html>
```